# Python Bot send message in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

In Discord there is a 2000 characters limit to send message so we need to split and send multiple message. I using the below code, it works, but the message doesn't send in the specified order, so I used `sleep()` after every message. Now it works but still the message sometime doesn't follow the order. Because of the mixed order, while reading long message it gets confusing.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Message 1".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
    await sleep(.5)

    msg = "Message 2".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
    await sleep(.5)

    msg = "Message 3".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
    await sleep(.5)

    msg = "Message 4 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

I need after every message it should check the message sent and then it should send the second message after the last message. Or is there any other solution to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might seem like a easy task, but it's actually quite complicated. One also might recommend to use `bot.wait_for_message(...)`, but there's loopholes in that logic (the bot sent the message `wait_for_message` is ready) since it isn't meant for doing your task.

The best method I can think of now is to make a custom future event and add a `wait_for` after sending the message. The future should register an `on_message` event that checks if the bot's message had been sent.

```
import asyncio

def wait(check):
    f = asyncio.Future(loop=bot.loop)

    async def _wait(future, check):
        @bot.listen()
        async def on_message(msg):
            if check(msg):
                bot.remove_listener(on_message)
                future.set_result(msg)

    asyncio.ensure_future(_wait(f, check), loop=bot.loop)
    return f

def ping_check(content):
    def check(msg):
        if msg.content == content and msg.author == bot.user:
            return True
        return False
    return check

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Message 1 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    f = wait(ping_check(msg))
    await bot.say(msg)
    await asyncio.wait_for(f, None, loop=bot.loop)

    msg = "Message 2 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    f = wait(ping_check(msg))
    await bot.say(msg)
    await asyncio.wait_for(f, None, loop=bot.loop)

    msg = "Message 3 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    f = wait(ping_check(msg))
    await bot.say(msg)
    await asyncio.wait_for(f, None, loop=bot.loop)

    msg = "Message 4 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    f = wait(ping_check(msg))
    await bot.say(msg)
    await asyncio.wait_for(f, None, loop=bot.loop)
```

I further edited this solution to include a `check()` this makes the `wait()` function a lot more flexible which removed the previously hardcoded checks.

Comment: Yes for now its sending messages in order.  if there is anything i need about this question i will message you. Thank you bro...

Answer (score 1):

Just add a slight delay between the messages:

```
from asyncio import sleep

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Message 1 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
    await sleep(.5)

    msg = "Message 2 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
    await sleep(.5)

    msg = "Message 3 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
    await sleep(.5)

    msg = "Message 4 {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: @Demotry looks like a problem in your `on_command_error` coroutine.

Comment: hi @Patrick i updated `on_command_error`  which i added for `commands.CommandInvokeError` above.

Comment: you should probably ask a separate question. When you do, please include what `exceptions` is and where it's coming from

Comment: what is `exceptions.Halt`?  If you unregister your `on_command_error`, (just comment out the `@bot.event`) how does that change the error you're getting?

Comment: Just now removed all `on_command_error`  now when i run command with `await sleep(.5)` it gives a error i added in above.

Comment: You have some other object (a command) also named `sleep`.  Change the import to `import asyncio` and then the calls to `await asyncio.sleep(.5)`

Comment: Yes exactly same its now working. i added a `sleep` command before now i renamed it now its working fine... thank you...